# Will there be any memory leaks if I erase an element from a nested map/set in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, unordered-map, unordered-set

I'm trying to erase a `unordered_set<int>` from a `unordered_map<int, unordered_set<int>>`.

What will happen to the `unordered_set<int>` after I erase it from the unordered_map? Will it still stay in the memory, thus causing memory leaks? If yes, what should I do to totally remove it from the memory?

I tried the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

unordered_map<int, unordered_set<int>> mp;

int main()
{
    mp[0] = unordered_set<int>();
    mp[0].insert(1);
    mp[0].insert(2);

    unordered_set<int>& st = mp[0];
    cout << st.size() << endl;
    mp.erase(0);
    cout << st.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is 2 and 0. It seems that the element in the unordered_set has been removed, but what about the unordered_set itself? Is it still staying in the memory?

Comment: You're overthinking it. Standard containers take care of memory for you. The only thing wrong here is the dangling reference, the use of which is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not stay in memory. The destructor will be called and the memory will be freed. In this respect `unordered_set` objects are no different to any other object you may want to put in the STL container.

See the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/erase/) on `std::unordered_map::erase`:

> This effectively reduces the container size by the number of elements removed, calling each element's destructor.

Answer (score 1):

No, `unordered_set` will be freed from the memory because the destructor of `unordered_set` will be called (as it works with any object used as value in `unordered_map`). In most cases, you may trust STL containers to do memory management for you.

Also note that you are using a **dangling reference** here, which is undefined behaviour:

```
unordered_set<int>& st = mp[0];
cout << st.size() << endl;
mp.erase(0);
cout << st.size() << endl;  // <-- calling size() on a dangling reference
```

The reference has been invalidated when calling [`unordered_map::erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase):

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other
>   iterators and references are not invalidated.